# Using CollectionViewSource for SelectedItem.ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I'm trying to get CollectionViewSource to work for an ObservableCollection of a SelectedItem object but I'm not getting what I am expecting. The ListView does not have items updated with the SelectedItem property change.

I have an `ObservableCollection<Car> Cars` with a `SelectedCar` object which is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the ListView the ObservableCollection is attached to. All is fine here.

The `Car` class has an `ObservableCollection<string> Tyres` which is the object of interest here.

From here, I'd like to bind another ListView's `ItemsSource` to `SelectedCar.Tyres` object. Initially the `SelectedCar` is null because there is nothing selected in the original Cars ListView. The reason I am using ICollectionView here is because I need filtering done on the Tyres ListView.

In my ViewModel, I have declared the ICollectionView as:

```
private ICollectionView tyreCollectionView;
public ICollectionView TyreCollectionView
{
    get
    {
        return this.tyreCollectionView;
    }
}
```

And, in the Setter of `SelectedCar`, I do this:

```
this.tyreCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value.Tyres);
this.tyreCollectionView.Filter += this.FilterByTyreName;
```

As for XAML, the ListView in question is bound to the ICollectionView as follows.

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding YCollectionView}/>
```

I tried calling `this.tyreCollectionView.Refresh()` also but this doesn't do anything as well. The ListView does not have any results populated. When I tried to debug my code for the `SelectedCar` setter, I can see that the ICollectionView does show the items in `value.Tyres`, just that these values do not appear in the ListView.

I am not able to initialise `yCollectionView` in my MainViewModel's constructor because during that stage, the `SelectedCar` object is still null and doing something like `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.SelectedCar.Tyres)` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Can anyone guide me on this issue? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Does `YCollectionView` property setter contain `NotifyPropertyChanged` realization? Maybe you can try to set `ItemsSource` of ListView for tires directly in the setter of `SelectedCar`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have not implemented property changed notifier for the YCollectionView at the moment. I shall give it a try when I'm back at work tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi, ok then, write if it will help)

Comment: Sure, I'll be back with results tomorrow :)

Comment: Hey man, your suggestion was spot on! My ICollectionView updates properly now. If you would like to post an answer, please do so and I will accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments answer is the realization `NotifyPropertyChanged` for the `YCollectionView` property like that.

```
private ICollectionView tyreCollectionView;    
public ICollectionView TyreCollectionView
{
    get
    {
        return this.tyreCollectionView;
    }
    set
    {
        this.tyreCollectionView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "TyreCollectionView" );
    }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
{
    if ( PropertyChanged != null )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
    }
}
```